# Grouping and Sorting By distinct values in Oracle's SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, aggregate-functions

I have table like this:

| id | full_name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | John Smith |
| 2 | Smith John |
| 3 | Jim Jonson |
| 4 | JimJonson |

I want to get something like this:

| id | full_name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | John Smith |
| 3 | Jim Jonson |

So, I need `SELECT DISTINCT full_name FROM table`, so that

- `John Smith` and `Smith John`  to be one and the same, also
- `Jim Jonson` and `JimJonson`

I hope I explained it well. Can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can split the full_name values by initial capitals of name and surnames in unpivoted manner, and sort alphabetically, and combine by using `LISTAGG()` function, and apply `MIN()` aggregation at the last step such as

```
WITH t(id,full_name) AS
(
 SELECT 1, 'John Smith' FROM dual UNION ALL 
 SELECT 2, 'Smith John' FROM dual UNION ALL
 SELECT 3, 'Jim Jonson' FROM dual UNION ALL
 SELECT 4, 'JimJonson'  FROM dual 
), t2 AS
(
  SELECT id,  
         TRIM(SUBSTR(full_name,column_value,LEAD(column_value,1,LENGTH(full_name)) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY id,column_value)-1)) AS names
    FROM t,
         TABLE(CAST(MULTISET(SELECT REGEXP_INSTR(full_name,'[A-Z]+',1,level)
                               FROM dual 
                            CONNECT BY level <= REGEXP_COUNT(full_name,'[A-Z]')) AS sys.odcivarchar2list ))                        
), t3 AS
(
 SELECT id, LISTAGG(names,' ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY id,names) AS full_name
   FROM t2
  GROUP BY id                           
)
SELECT MIN(id) AS min_id, full_name
  FROM t3 
 GROUP BY full_name
 ORDER BY min_id
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=2beb3c429a8865da12b858d304b52631)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Step-by-step. Read comments within code.

```
SQL> with test (id, full_name) as
  2    -- sample data
  3    (select 1, 'John Smith' from dual union all
  4     select 2, 'Smith John' from dual union all
  5     select 3, 'Jim Jonson' from dual union all
  6     select 4, 'JimJonson'  from dual
  7    ),
```

---

```
  8  temp as
  9    -- split full name to rows
 10    (select id,
 11       regexp_substr(full_name, '[^ ]+', 1, column_value) val,
 12      column_value cv
 13     from test cross join
 14       table(cast(multiset(select level from dual
 15                           connect by level <= regexp_count(full_name, ' ') + 1
 16                          ) as sys.odcinumberlist))
 17    ),
 18  temp2 as
 19    -- aggregate full name with no space between "words"
 20    (select id,
 21       listagg(val, '') within group (order by val) full_name
 22     from temp
 23     group by id
 24    ),
 25  temp3 as
 26    -- fetch only distinct values
 27    (select min(b.id) id,
 28            b.full_name
 29     from temp2 b
 30     group by b.full_name
 31    )
```

---

```
 32  -- finally, join TEMP3 and sample data
 33  select b.id,
 34         a.full_name
 35  from test a join temp3 b on b.id = a.id
 36  order by a.id;

        ID FULL_NAME
---------- ----------------------------------------
         1 John Smith
         3 Jim Jonson

SQL>
```